# How to remove grey border from Blastula emails in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, blastula

By default, Blastula encloses RMarkdown emails with a gray border. This looks wrong on Gmail, as Gmail already adds a gray border to emails, boxing all your rmarkdown mails with a white box inside a gray box, inside a another white box inside yer another gray box.

[image]

The code I used to produce this email is as follows:

```
informe_html <- readr::read_file("html_email.html")
  email <- compose_email(body = md(informe_html))
```

My html file has no borders at all, just the dark grey background over a white background. The remaining light gray, white and light gray borders are added by Blastula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `email` object produced from `compose_email()` contains HTML, so you can use string manipulation to change the appearance of the email. When you inspect the HTML code, the grey looks like it is coming from the `<body>` tag, which has the style attribute: `background-color:#f6f6f6`. Removing this tag should remove the grey border around the message.

`blastula_message` objects seem to have two versions of the HTML for the message:

- `html_str`: The raw HTML stored as a character string.
- `html_html`: The HTML stored as a `html` object.

The first is what actually gets sent when you use `smtp_send()` and the second seems to be what you see when you preview the message via  `print(email)`. To be safe you can remove the `background-color` attribute from both:

```r
email$html_str <- sub(
  x = email$html_str,
  pattern = "background-color:#f6f6f6(;)",
  replacement = "")

email$html_html <- sub(
  x = email$html_html,
  pattern = "background-color:#f6f6f6(;)",
  replacement = "")
```

The `(;)` in the pattern is in case `background-color` isn't the only style attribute for `<body>`.

When you preview `email` the grey border should now be gone as the background of the mail will now be transparent.